# FastAPI: How to generate a readable scheme from IntEnum in openapi.json with the correct keys, not digital ones?

Tags: enums, fastapi, openapi, pydantic, openapi-generator

My IntEnum class:

```py
class Role(IntEnum):
    client = 1
    manager = 2
    admin = 3
```

What I got in generated openapi.json:

```json
{
  enum: [1, 2, 3],
  title: "Role",
  type: "integer"
}
```

What I need:

```json
{
  enum: {
    client: 1,
    manager: 2,
    admin: 3
  },
  title: "Role",
  type: "integer"
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The names in an `IntEnum` are only used internally. Any reason you can't use a `StrEnum`?

Comment: I use this IntEnum as type for field in db and I wouldn't store roles and statuses as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your attention, but I found a solution:)
I should to override `__get_pydantic_json_schema__` method in all my classes where I need custom schema generation.